# Testing C# MySQL connection pooling fails with Exception: Connection must be valid and open

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, connection-pooling

I am trying to use connection pooling on MySQL's .net connector 6.6.4.0 to serve multiple threads using the code below:

```
static public uint uNonQuery(string query)
        {

                using (Connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Its open..>!!!!");
                    }

                    Connection.Open();

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, Connection);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'identity'", Connection);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                    uint ret = 0;

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ret = Convert.ToUInt32(dt.Rows[0]["identity"]);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            ret = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    else
                        ret = 0;

                    Connection.Close();
                    return ret;
                }
        }
```

My connection string is

```
"server = 127.0.0.1; user id = ****; password = ****; database = testdb; pooling=true; maximumpoolsize=500;"
```

And the thread for testing is

```
static void DoInserts(object o)
{
    int i = (int)o;
    Console.WriteLine("Insert Thread {0} launched", i);


    for(int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
    {
        uint insertId = DataLayer.uNonQuery(String.Format("INSERT INTO testdb.dbtest (writeNo,strNo) VALUES ({0},'x={0} thread={1}')", x, i));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Insert Thread {0} completed", i);

}
```

I get the exception **Exception: Connection must be valid and open.** after about 6 inserts on 2 concurrent threads, is there something else i need to do enable pooling to work correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, why do you check if the connection is open then open it regardless??

Comment: @DanielKelley Hi. I tested if its open before i call Open() and it is not open before the Open() call, which is expected, although connection pooling is enabled.

Comment: `(Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open` indicates there is something wrong with the logic of your code. If you would open the connection in scope, it is no need to check whether it is open already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line `using (Connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))` you are using the variable `Connection`. Where is this variable defined? Is it static? You should define it in scope of `uNonQuery`. If variable `Connection` is static, then it is possible the connection is closed after a new function call to `uNonQuery` has opened it.

Example:
- Thread 1 calls `uNonQuery` and opens, does it things.
- Thread 2 calls `uNonQuery`, opens the connection, 
- Thread 1 closes `Connection`
- Thread 2 cannot do its thing because the connection was suddenly closed.

If the above is not the cause of your problem I would need more of your code to examine the problem.

Comment: Hi, it seems that the Connection object was defined as static, which caused the clash. I just tested it again without static and it completed 20 concurrent threads with 10 000 inserts each. Thank you very much.